# How to Bulk 'remove code cert' from a word document and then resign it useing my own certificate

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have 1000 Microsoft Word documents with a macro that is signed by an old supplier.

I need to **remove the old cert and sign it with my own**. I can do this manually,  but well..  would like to script it.

Any suggestions on how I can do this using a script?

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no support in the VBA object model to sign a macro project programmatically.

Assuming you only have to replace the signatures of the 1000 macros a single time you are probably best of writing short script using a UI-automation tool such as **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)**.